# Perform operation with different users

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am developing a file manager in `Django` using `Python 3.5.2`. I need to manage files that are owned by different Linux user, but each user do not have any permission to read other users' files.

I have tried to develop a `root` daemon process that only accept commands from main application and cannot be accessed directly. The daemon uses `os.fork()` to start a new child that will perform `seteuid()` and `setguid()`, then perform file manager operation.

However, I do not have much success in dealing with forked child. What I need is I am able to run commands under different users with `seteuid()` and `setguid()`, so that each users can manage their own files properly.

The following are my code in Django:

***Main App `views.py`***

```
def file_operation(request):

    user = {
        'username': request.session.get("username"),
        'home_dir': request.session.get('home_dir'),
        'uid': request.session.get("uid"),
        'gid': request.session.get("gid")
    }

    url = u'%s:%s/files?username=%s&home_dir=%s&uid=%s&gid=%s' % (
        settings.DAEMON_FILE_HOST, settings.DAEMON_FILE_PORT,
        user['username'], user['home_dir'], user['uid'], user['gid']
    )

    return ProxyRequest().proxy_view(request, url)
```

`ProxyRequest()` is a custom class that pass all the request from Main App to another url (daemon) and retrieve the response.

***Daemon `views.py`***

```
def connector(request):

    user = {
        'username': request.GET.get("username"),
        'home_dir': request.GET.get('home_dir'),
        'uid': int(request.GET.get("uid")),
        'gid': int(request.GET.get("gid"))
    }

    newpid = os.fork()
    response = None
    if newpid == 0:
        setegid(user['gid'])
        seteuid(user['uid'])
        response = RunCommand(user, request.GET.copy(), request.POST.copy(), request.FILES.copy())

    os.waitpid(newpid,0)
    return response
```

`RunCommand()` is the backend process that perform file operation based on different type of `request` received.

If I do not use `os.fork()`, my daemon process will stuck in another user after `seteuid()` instead of `root`, so I can no longer change the `euid` of the process to read another user directory.

I am not expert in Python, so maybe I am not doing this correct? Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Why not use [`sudo`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)?

Comment: Is `sudo` a solution even if it is running in `django` app? as far as I know, I would need `subprocess` to perform any `sudo` operation, and it does not allow me to create or modify the file directly.

Comment: Why can't you create or modify a file?

Comment: the file manager required live editing, so I need to get full file content.`sudo` will allow me to create file but how do I save content from my front-end textarea into the new file using `sudo` without `open()`?

Comment: [1] Read the file, load it into text area - use sudo + open, [2] Let the user edit the file (no need sudo here) [3] When user needs to save, open the file in `w` mode (use sudo) and save the file

Comment: how am I suppose to perform `sudo` and `open` without using `subprocess`? by default, django is launched as `apache` user